# Add Application Error on Default Web Site (IIS 7.5, Windows server 2008R2)

Tags: iis

I am trying to add a .net application to my Default Web Site on IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008 R2. The Default Web Site currently serves ASP Classic pages (not sure if that is relevant) and I'm trying to setup some aspx pages. But I can't even add a new application, i keep getting an error of

`"value does not fall within range"`

I have no idea what this means?

Please see my screenshot for more information:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLCua.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Although quite tedious, you could try checking the settings in the apphost config file. You can find it at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
Look for errors in names, sometimes spaces can be replaced with %20% by Visual Studio which should be removed, also if you have deleted something manually in your file system, this will not have been updated in the applicationhost config file, so any references would need to be removed manually also.

Regards, and good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did check your answer out, but in the end i just created a ASP Classic App and switched it to DefaultAppPool, this made it work, still no idea why it just wouldn't let me create it that way. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well i never found a solution apart from Creating the App as ASP Classic (which would allow me too do it) and then switching the AppPool to DefaultAppPool which in turn lets me server ASPX pages.

So, Kind of solved for now...